# Dynamic password for Node-Red Email

Tags: node-red

I am trying to assign "Userid" for "node-red-node-email" node dynamically by external node.
According to Node Red documents , the "Userid" filed can be assigned by "msg.from" but there is no guide for how to assign "Password" field.
anybody knows any solution?

Answer (score 0):

The `msg.from` does not change the `userid` that is used to authenticate with the SMTP server, it just changes the value used for the `from` field in the email.

At this point you can not change the `userid` or `password` dynamically with the stock email node.